# if i update from 19.10 to 20.04 lts will i lose my additional Drivers?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, upgrade, updates

i want to update to latest version of ubuntu but i'm really scared of losing the additional drivers, btw i'm scared because it was really hard to download the gtx 1070 driver and and make them work.

Comment: Drivers need to be recompiled for every new kernel. Since Ubuntu updates your kernel every two-three weeks or so as part of normal security updates, you should have encountered this problem before....

Comment: Refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic where you'll notice only supported releases of Ubuntu and flavors are on-topic for this site. For *focal fossa* [20.04] questions you'll need to use a development support site such as IRC (#ubuntu+1) or Ubuntu Forums, or wait until after release for this site (expected release date for Ubuntu 20.04 is 23rd April 2020 when your question will be on-topic here).

Comment: @user535733 What if one uses DKMS?

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu, you can contribute as a tester. If it fails you can continue reporting with the result about 3 days later.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading to a newer release upgrades all packages that were installed from the default Ubuntu repositories including drivers. Upgrading Ubuntu to a newer release does not automatically upgrade manually installed packages that were download from the internet.

It is possible to allow keeping PPA and third party repositories enabled when upgrading to a newer Ubuntu release (to Ubuntu 18.10 and later) by using the `RELEASE_UPGRADER_ALLOW_THIRD_PARTY` environment variable.

GUI:

```
RELEASE_UPGRADER_ALLOW_THIRD_PARTY=1 update-manager -d
```

Command line:

```
RELEASE_UPGRADER_ALLOW_THIRD_PARTY=1 do-release-upgrade -d
```